# Should I be concerned if Turbo Tax computes my rental depreciation higher this year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I used Turbo Tax Premier for 2012, and I have just completed my tax forms for 2013 using Turbo Tax Deluxe.  It imported the numbers from the previous tax return, the only number that changed was that I had it rented for 10 months in 2012, and for the whole year in 2013.  This year my depreciation expense for the rental property increased by 60% over last year.  It seems strange if two more months of depreciation makes that much of a difference.  Is there a reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: Check and compare the worksheets. Doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sift through the return to uncover the source of this discrepancy. You are correct, a rental put in service for 10 months with have 5/6 the depreciation of a full year.
Something else is going on.

Comment: I looked at the schedule E worksheet and it was computing based on the same home/land values, but one other factor is that the previous year was my first year renting it.  Anyway, I'll have an accountant take a look at the forms and see if I can get more info on the reason.